# How to bundle current schema/tables into user environment(Windows)

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to bundle PostgreSQL into my Windows application.
I have downloaded a binary PostgreSQL and created lots of tables under the new schema.
I was wondering if I could just copy the current database into the directory user would select.

Question:

1. Do I have to run 'initdb' in my installer? If that is the case, I think the current schema/tables are removed so I should run the external sql file which includes all of table creation commands. Is that correct?
2. What is the simplest way for me to bundle my current schema/tables into the user environment through Windows installer steps.

Add:

I realized that I couldn't just copy the current database into other system as it depends on the OS user in Windows.
I will run 'initdb' in my Installer and also run a table creation script.

Comment: Is PostgreSQL mandatory in your application? if it is desktop application, i think sqlite database is enough, like they use in skype, viber and many other programs. What programming language do you use? Do you use any ORMs?

Comment: I'm using Xojo (Visual Basic like). Tried SQLite before but it is not scalable so decided to change it to PostgreSQL. It works great well.

Comment: You should at least allow the user to specify a location for the data. And the (binary) form of the data depends on the platform, so it will be hard to supply platform-independent data, an import step at installation-time will probably be the most portable. This is also a good way to test if the PG installation is running and functional.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Great.